# How can I modify the space between a DevExpress candlestick?

Tags: .net, wpf, charts, devexpress

I want to increase the space between candle sticks since my candles overlap when I increase the candle width.

How can I do this from within my xaml code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should decrease the [range](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfChartsAxisRangetopic) of values displayed by an date-time axis. To accomplish this task use an instance of the `AxisRange` type that can be accessed via the [Axis.Range](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfChartsAxis_Rangetopic) property.